# problem about a simple gimp script

Tags: gimp

I have taken photos from my negative and I want to invert the color in a batch, I have "somehow" copy and paste a script like this:

```
(define (batch-negative pattern)
  (let* ((filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1))))
    (while (not (null? filelist))
           (let* ((filename (car filelist))
                  (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                              filename filename)))
                  (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
             (gimp-invert RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                   image drawable)
             (gimp-levels-stretch RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                   image drawable)
             (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                             image drawable filename filename)
             (gimp-image-delete image))
           (set! filelist (cdr filelist)))))
```

I try to follow the tutorial, but fails, I think there is something wrong at the line for `gimp-invert`, but I don't know where, can anyone help?

Thanks!

Edit: FYI, I am using ubuntu 10.10, thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solve, I added too many parameters for `gimp-levels-stretch` and `gimp-invert`, modified code is as below:

```
(define (batch-negative pattern)
  (let* ((filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1))))
    (while (not (null? filelist))
           (let* ((filename (car filelist))
                  (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                              filename filename)))
                  (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
             (gimp-invert RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                   image drawable)
             (gimp-levels-stretch RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                   image drawable)
             (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                             image drawable filename filename)
             (gimp-image-delete image))
           (set! filelist (cdr filelist)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

while i was browsing about the same problem i found your answer... but you delievered in your answer the exact same script again ;)
so here is the fixed one, with the removed 2 parameters, which works fine:

```
(define (batch-negative pattern)
  (let* ((filelist (cadr (file-glob pattern 1))))
    (while (not (null? filelist))
           (let* ((filename (car filelist))
                  (image (car (gimp-file-load RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                                              filename filename)))
                  (drawable (car (gimp-image-get-active-layer image))))
             (gimp-invert drawable)
             (gimp-levels-stretch drawable)
             (gimp-file-save RUN-NONINTERACTIVE
                             image drawable filename filename)
             (gimp-image-delete image))
           (set! filelist (cdr filelist)))))
```